# Jsxgraph angle updated on condition

Tags: jsxgraph

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/distrib/jsxgraph.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/distrib/jsxgraphcore.js"></script>
<div id="jxgbox" class="jxgbox" style="width:600px; height:600px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('jxgbox', {boundingbox:[-5,5,5,-5], grid:false, axis:false, keepaspectratio: true, showcopyright:false});
s1= board.create('slider',[[2,-4],[4,-4],[1,3,5]]);
var p=[];
var a=[];
var f=[];
p[1]=board.create('point',[0,0], {withlabel:false, visible:true, fixed:true, color:'#000000', size:2, name:'O'});
p[0]= board.create('point',[0,function(){return p[1].Y()+s1.Value();}], {visible:false, name:'X'});
c= board.create('circle',[p[1],p[0]], {strokeWidth:2, dash:0, fillColor:'#2ECCFA', strokeColor:'#0080FF', fillOpacity:0});
f[0]=function(x){return Math.pow(-1,x)*Math.sqrt(s1.Value()*s1.Value()-x*x);}
for (i=2; i<5; i++)
{p[i]=board.create('glider',[i-4,f[0](i-4),c], {withLabel:true, color:'#000000', size:2})}
poly1=board.create('polygon',[p[4],p[2],p[3],p[1]]);
a[0]=board.create('nonreflexangle',[p[3],p[2],p[4]],{visible:true});
a[1]=board.create('angle',[p[4],p[1],p[3]],{visible:false});
a[2]=board.create('angle',[p[3],p[1],p[4]],{visible:true});
a[0].label.setText('&theta;');
a[1].label.setText(2+'&theta;');
a[2].label.setText(2+'&theta;');
displayangle = function(){
for (i=1; i<3; i++)
{a[i].setAttribute({visible:false});
}
for (i=1; i<3; i++)
{if (a[i].Value().toFixed(3)/a[0].Value().toFixed(3)==2){
a[i].setAttribute({visible:true, withLabel:true});}}
}
for (i=0; i<5; i++)
{p[i].on('drag',displayangle);}
</script>
```

I attempt to draw a graph to demonstrate a simple geometric property of circle with JSXgraph, i.e. 
 angle at center twice angle at the circumference
I didn't observe any mistake i made. The issue now is. The angle is visible occasionally, when i dragged alone those free points on the circle.

My instinct tell me that I did something wrong. Please kindly help me out to check.

Answer (score 0):

The test in function `displayangle()` whether angle `a[i]` is twice angle `a[0]` is numerically unstable. My suggestion is to replace the test by the following:

```
displayangle = function(){
    for (i=1; i<3; i++) {
        a[i].setAttribute({visible:false});
    }
    for (i=1; i<3; i++) {
        if (Math.abs(a[i].Value() - 2*a[0].Value()) < 0.00001) {
            a[i].setAttribute({visible:true, withLabel:true});
        }
    }
}
```